# Node.js os.freemem() do not work correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using this method of Node.js Os module: [os.freemem()](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_freemem)

This is my sample code:

```
const os = require('os');

const bytesToSize = (bytes) => {
const sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'];
if (bytes == 0) return '0 Byte';
const i = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1024)));
return Math.round(bytes / Math.pow(1024, i), 2) + ' ' + sizes[i];
};

 console.log('free memory : ', bytesToSize(os.freemem()));
 console.log('total memory : ', bytesToSize(os.totalmem()));
```

after  I run my code, I give the below result:

free memory :  164 MB

total memory :  8 GB

but my OS system monitor show me:

[image: os free memory]

Why is there such a difference?

Comment: you are mixing data measurement... 1 KB = 1000 bytes. 1 KiB = 1024. Your sizes 
 array should be `['Bytes', 'KiB', 'MiB', 'GiB', 'TiB']` if you are using 1024

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently system monitor doesn't show you the **free** memory, but the **available** one.

Node's `OS.freemem()` and `free` command use the information from `/proc/meminfo`:

```
klaimmore@klaimmore-HP-ZBook-14:/rep$ sudo cat /proc/meminfo | grep Mem
MemTotal:       16320372 kB
MemFree:         1274072 kB
MemAvailable:   10618284 kB
klaimmore@klaimmore-HP-ZBook-14:/rep$ node -p "require('os').freemem()/1024"
1254828
klaimmore@klaimmore-HP-ZBook-14:/rep$ free -k
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       16320372     4684776     1273228      678996    10362368    10617452
Swap:       2097148           0     2097148
```